# How to add js file to some addresses in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some pages like this:
http://mydomainname.com/product/product-name/edit/
in this address, product-name section is not a fixed name in address and it shows product name.
I want to add a js file to this page but this is not an actual page.
also I can't add my js file to whole site because it has conflict with some other js files.
Please tell me is there anyway to add js file to this pages?
(Something like:
if page address has edit at the end then enqueue script. . .
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if edit exists in url then add script tag

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if (strpos($actual_link,'/edit') !== false && strpos($actual_link,'/product/') !== false) {
    echo "<script></script>";
}
```